# Sort JavaScript Object according to Object property but maintain index

Tags: javascript

> If presented with an object like this in JavaScript:

```
var data = [
            {"Person Name": "Amy", "Age":"46", "sex":"female"}
            {"Person Name": "John", "Age":"22", "sex":"male"}
            {"Person Name": "Mike", "Age":"62", "sex":"male"}
            {"Person Name": "Gav", "Age":"undefined", "sex":"male"}
           ]
```

and want to find the Maximum Age but also want to return the index value too, ie '2' for

```
data[2]["Age"]
```

in this example, how do I code it?  The data object I am using however contains over 1000 entries and has undefined values for age, so needs to be searched.

My solution so far is:

```
function maxIndex(/*string*/ property, /*array*/ searchArray){

    var maxIndex = 0;
    var maxValue = searchArray[0][property];

    for(i=1;i<searchArray.length;i++){

        if(searchArray[i][property] > maxValue){
            maxValue = searchArray[i][property];
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }

   return maxIndex; 
}
```

called by:

```
maxAgeIndex = maxIndex("Age", data);
```

This doesn't seem to work.  I can't sort the data object on the "Age" property as I lose the index number.

Comment: That cannot be how your object really looks; the outer `{ }` should be square brackets (`[ ]`), which makes it an array.

Comment: Also I'm not sure I see what sorting has to do with this; you're just looking for the index of the record with the largest value for some property, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  I'm still learning JavaScript so is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: No this looks fine, except for the mistakes I described. At least, I think it's OK otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're only updating the maximum value when the array element is **less than** the largest value you've seen so far. That should be a greater-than test:

```
  if (searchArray[i][property] > maxValue) {
```

Also, declare "i" with `var`:

```
for (var i = 1; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to do with a functional approach, you could try something like this:

```
var ages = data.map(function(item){return parseInt(item.Age) || 0});
var maxAge = Math.max.apply(Math, ages);
var maxAgeIndex = ages.indexOf(maxAge);
```

(the `|| 0` means that 'undefined' will become 0)

---

Or, as Pointy suggested, you could use reduce:

```
var oldestPerson = data.reduce(function(memo, item){
   return parseInt(memo.Age) < parseInt(item.Age) ? item : memo
})
```

Comment: It'd probably be better to do this with `.reduce()`, keeping track of an object with the biggest value and its index.

Comment: oh, that could be way more interesting.. Updated!